# Transposing rows into columns Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, web-analytics

I'm looking to aggregate a customer journey from a eCommerce website within SQL however first I must transpose a table which currently stores each unique view of a URL as a rows with a unique primary index (the session id) and secondly an column for index number, to sequence steps taken in the journey alongside the type of page this is, aliased as a 'page type.

I'm looking to essentially transpose this table so each pageview index number is a column and the value of the column is populated with the corresponding page type value.

I've tired using CASE and TD_UNPIVOT to achieve this however had little luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include at the minimum some sample data and desired result. What you've tried and what you are getting would be helpful too.

Comment: You describe PIVOT, not UNPIVOT :-) What are you trying to achieve? NPath might be a good choice

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.